How can I Add Reading Time Estimates to Your Next.js v15 Blog Without Client-Side Rendering?
I am currently working on a blog website built with Next.js v15.0.3. I aim to integrate a time estimator feature for the blog, using the reading-time-estimator package. However, I have encountered an issue: this package requires the text to be passed in for estimation, which would result in client-side rendering. This approach would cause all of the blogs to be treated as client-side pages, which I would prefer to avoid.
I would greatly appreciate any assistance or suggestions regarding an alternative package or approach allowing me to estimate reading time without making the blogs client-side pages.
Below is the code for one of my blogs:
enter image description here
